# How can I get react-bootstrap to load without breaking react-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, requirejs, react-bootstrap

I'm building an application using ReactBootstrap. I was having trouble figuring out how to place my code into separate files, so I started using require.js. I started a separate project as a playground to experiment with requiring the various modules I need in my bigger project.

I have been able to get react (and react-dom) working on its own. However, as soon as I perform a require() on react-bootstrap, I get the following error:

```
GET http://localhost:5000/static/react-dom.js              require.js:1952
Uncaught Error: Script error for "react-dom"               require.js:165
```

Please note that the above address is not the correct location for react-dom. I have no idea why it's looking for it in that location. This can be seen in my config.js file, which accurately depicts the location of my relevant JavaScript pre-requisite modules:

```
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: "/static",
  paths: {
    jquery: "vendors/jquery/dist/jquery",
    jsx: "vendors/jsx-requirejs-plugins/js/jsx",
    JSXTransformer: "vendors/jsx-requirejs-plugins/js/JSXTransformer",
    react: "vendors/react/react-with-addons",
    react_dom: "vendors/react/react-dom",
    bootstrap: "vendors/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap",
    react_bootstrap: "vendors/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap",
    text: "vendors/requirejs-text/text",
  },
  jsx: {
    fileExtension: ".js"
  },
});
```

At this point, I am not even rendering anything of interest (in the name of figuring this out). This can be seen by looking at my rather empty app.js file:

```
requirejs(
    ["jquery", "react", "react_dom", "react_bootstrap"],
    function($, React, ReactDOM) {
});
```

There is no error when I change the above code to:

```
requirejs(
    ["jquery", "react", "react_dom"],
    function($, React, ReactDOM) {
});
```

Adding bootstrap to the list does not help. It is also worth noting that JQuery is being correctly loaded from http://localhost:5000/static/vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.js

For context, my index.html file looks as below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <script src="/static/vendors/requirejs/require.js"></script>
  <script src="/static/config.js"></script>
  <script src="/static/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

To summarize: I get an error with a specific Library – in particular, it is being looked for in the wrong place – but that error only shows up when additionally requiring react-bootstrap.

What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I took the liberty of naming, within config.js, react-dom as "react_dom", mostly to get around the fact that dashes don't work without encasing them in quotes. react-bootstrap was then specifically asking for react-dom, which is why the wrong URL was being hit.

Moving forward with the correct naming scheme, everything works smashingly!